# Need help with NOT Gate oscillator circuit

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator, waveform, not-gate

Sorry, if the question seems silly, but I really need someone to help me understand the below oscillator circuit. How can the oscillation begin, if there are no initial conditions? All analysis shown in textbooks assume an initial condition of either '0' or '1' on input/output. But how does it work in real time? When the IC is powered on, the input side should be floating (high Z state), isn't it? What am I missing here? Also, I read somewhere that this circuit has a nasty habit of altering the duty cycle if operated for long? How is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's not an oscillator - if you believe it is or should be then please provide a link to some site that justifies it.

Comment: Any noise on the input will set the initial condition to 1 or 0. A CMOS Not gate has a fixed low and high threshold voltage. Lets say, initial condition is '0', it takes T seconds for the delay of the not gate, and the resistor capacitor sets the discharge/charge time hence the frequency of the oscillation.

Comment: @Andy aka- Here is the link where I found the idea. Though, there are multiple gates, I have included only one to simplify my question. http://www.gadgetronicx.com/square-wave-generator-logic-gates/

Comment: Maybe if I designed a car with one bloody wheel it'll go faster. Voting to close this question as a waste of time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the schematic simplifications make the question pointless.

Comment: *I have included only one to simplify my question* Then that proves that you do not understand how the circuit works, which is indeed your question. **Why** do you think you can "safely" simplify a circuit while you do not understand its operation ?

Comment: @Andy, My point is, even if I copy paste the circuit from the website, my question would still remain the same- How will be the initial logic state decided, just after power-on. I really have no intention of wasting anyone's time.

Comment: It's quite simple really. You don't know why it works because you are unable to see why it works on a valid oscillator circuit and, if you'd have posted a valid circuit, someone would be able to explain the subtleties that your "joke" oscillator does not possess.

Comment: Here you go Andy! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVKeJ1vGNfo

Comment: @BrianDrummond ahh but does it go faster?

Comment: FakeMoustache- What I have understood is the logic states flip continuously due to metastable nature of such an arrangement. And the delay propagation from the output to the input will be decided by the cap charging time. Even if the circuit is not practical, my question remains the same for all square wave generators wired around logic gates.

Comment: @VinitShandilya , Can you edit your question, perhaps replace the offending circuit with a very specific oscillator that actually works. Include specific part #'s for logic gates. Also, it may matter how quickly the gate power supply comes up to its final value.

Comment: That circuit will not work using a 7400 (bipolar), it will oscillate using a CMOS equivalent such as a 74HC00.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Really appreciate it. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most oscillators when they are power-up or enabled are arranged to act as linear amplifiers with feedback from the output to input.  Circuit noise will then be successively amplified until it saturates.  From that point on circuit will oscillate at a frequency dependent upon what timing elements are present in the circuit (inductors, capacitors, circuit delays etc).

In the circuit you have above the feedback from the output of U1A to its input through R1 and R2 will bias that stage in its linear region.  The second stage will be biased with the same voltage due to its direct connection to U1A (The biasing will not be correct if there is significant current through R1 and R2 such as would be the case with bipolar 7400 series parts but will be true for CMOS parts).

The gain from the input of U1A to the output of U1B will almost certainly be greater than 1 so that any circuit noise at the input will appear at a magnified level at the output. Power-up transients may also act as the starting stimulus.

This magnified output is fed back through C1 to the input of the circuit to be amplified again.  After some number of circulations around the loop the signal will result in saturation and the circuit will stop being a linear amplifier.

At this point it will start oscillating:  Imagine that U1B has just transitioned d to a logic 1, this will have couple to the input via C1 bring the input to a logic 1 as well.  (ignore R1 for the moment it does not affect the concept of the oscillation).

C1 will then start discharging through R2 to U1A output which is at a logic zero.  After some time the input to U1A will fall to the point that U1A is in its linear region its output will start to rise (it was a logic zero) and in turn cause the output of U1B to fall - this fall of U1B output will be coupled to U1A input accelerating the transitioning ending up with the output of U1B being at a logic zero and U1A at a logic 1.  C1 now charges up through R2 until the input of U1A gets to the linear region when a transition in the opposite direction occurs.

R1 is necessary to avoid excessive current passing into the ESD diodes present at the input of most ICs - the circuit would still oscillate but the timing would be affected significantly.

It can be difficult to simulate oscillators because circuit simulators such as SPICE are too perfect and do not have any noise or circuit transients to start the oscillation.